# Gameobject располагается под canvas

Tags: unity3d

[image]

Здравствуйте, я только начала изучать unity и создаю игру пазлы. Когда я создаю gameobject, он располагается под canvas, и я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы gameobject распологался над ним. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Никак. У глобального canvas'a приоритет видимости перед всем на сцене, то есть игрок всегда видит интерфейс. Можете сделать ваш объект как image частью канваса и там уже выстроить приоритеты в окне иерархии (сначала отрисовываются верхние потом нижние и тд)

Comment: Как вы создаёте этот `gameObject` - с помощью скрипта или с помощью unity?

Answer (score 0):

О режимах "отрисовки" canvas почитайте [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html)

обратите внимание на режим **Screen Space - Camera** (пространство экрана - камера) в настройка компонента Canvas - выбрав этот режим так же нужно будет добавить камеру в поле Render Camera в компоненте Canvas

и поиграйтесь с **Plane Distance** в компоненте Canvas (выделев объект камеры и в окне Scene - можно увидеть на какой дистанции находится Canvas от камеры), не знаю как должны быть расположены объекты в вашей сцене, но думаю стоит с этим по экспериментировать, по крайней мере с помощью этого режима можно добиться того что, объект будет над холстом - если расположить "plane холста" камеры за трехмерным объектом